# Difference b/w 'git submodule update' and 'git pull'

Tags: git

What is the difference (if any) between 'git submodule update' and going into the git submodule directories and doing a 'git pull' on each?

Thanks

Comment: Please show what documentation/resources you found so far.

Answer (score 5):

There *is* a difference.  Also, I'll note that I studiously avoid submodules (aka sobmodules, for good reason: they make users very sad, or frustrated, or both).

#### A submodule is a separate Git repo

To distinguish between the "main" or "superproject" and each "submodule", let's call the top-level the superproject.  The sub-projects, sub-modules, or sub-repositories are all just "sub-repos" when we're working with them as repositories.

The superproject is an ordinary Git repository.  It has branches as usual, and commits that are on branches (and optionally commits that are *not* on branches, and so on).  It also, has, for each submodule, some recorded information:

- the URL of the submodule repository
- the path for the submodule repository
- a commit ID for the submodule

The first two items are stored in `.gitmodules`, which is an ordinary file in the top of the superproject work-tree that is formatted as a `git config` file (like `$HOME/.gitconfig` and `.git/config`).  The `.gitmodules` file can also contain additional information, per-submodule, but the first two items are required.

The third item—the commit ID—is stored in the repository as a file of type "gitlink".  This is the file that is updated when you change *which commit* is to be used for a specific submodule.

Let's say, for description sake, that the superproject has two submodules, `libbig` and `libsmall`, under paths `libs/big` and `libs/small`.  You'll therefore have a `.gitmodules` with the *paths* being `libs/big` and `libs/small`.  The *URLs* may be anything, depending on where the upstream repositories for `libbig` and `libsmall` are.

Meanwhile, Git will, in your superproject, have recorded a "file" named `libs/big` whose contents are `1a987f1356...` or whatever, and another "file" named `libs/small` whose contents are another big ugly SHA-1 hash.

#### Each submodule is put into "detached HEAD" state

When you clone and check out out the superproject, you don't have the submodules' repositories yet, you just have the `.gitmodules` file and the stored commit IDs.  Using `git submodule update` will clone the repositories into the appropriate directories.  Then, it will check out the *specific commits* identified by the gitlink entries.

This puts each sub-repo into "detached HEAD" state.

(This appears to be the case even for all the newer "branch" modes, though I have not experimented with this.)

#### `git pull` = `git fetch` + `git something`

Running `git pull` just runs, in effect, a somewhat limited `git fetch`, followed by one other Git command: either `git merge` or `git rebase`.  Which remote to use for the fetch step, and which branch to use for the merge-or-rebase step, is controlled by your current branch.  These two settings' values combine to make up the *upstream* setting for the current branch: if your current branch is `$branch`, your upstream is `$remote/$merge` where `$remote` is whatever is output when you run `git config --get branch.$branch.remote`, and `$merge` is the output you get when you run `git config --get branch.$branch.merge`.

Since your sub-repo is in "detached HEAD" state, its "current branch" is "no branch", also known as the special anonymous branch.  This by definition has neither a remote nor a merge setting.  Either `git config --get` command will fail.

The fetch step could still work, because Git defaults to fetching from `origin`.  The merge-or-rebase step will have to fail, though.  Hence `git pull` won't do much good.

#### `git submodule update` does something else entirely

Exactly what it does is highly configurable, so [see the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-submodule.html).  In general, if unconfigured, it just does any necessary initialization.  And, in general, it does not put the submodule on a branch: even if it updates the submodule based on a branch *name*, it still leaves it in "detached HEAD" state.

#### Recap

The general idea behind submodules is that you do not concern yourself with branches, only with raw commit-IDs.  Each submodule says "get me this *specific commit* from *this specific repository*", where the commit ID is recorded in the "gitlink" entry in the superproject, and the URL for the sub-repo is recorded in the `.gitmodules` file in the superproject.  The commit ID and the URL are therefore contained in a commit in the superproject: the ID through the gitlink "file", and the URL through the `.gitmodules` file.

To point some submodule at a *different* commit ID, you simply (hah) check out the new ID in the submodule itself, then go into the superproject and "git add" the new ID into the corresponding gitlink.  Using `git submodule add` does this second step for you.  You can do the second step manually almost as easily (with the exception that it is, or at least used to be, *very* easy to typo the operation in a bad way due to filename completion leaving a "/" in the path).  Once you have updated all the submodules, you then "git commit" the result to make a new commit in the superproject, recording the new gitlink hashes.

All the fussing-about that `git submodule` does for you is in service of doing the above two steps (leaving the `git commit` step for you to do manually).